# Getting ngTagsInput to work with answer from elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

i use elasticsearch to store tags, and want ngTagsInput to fetch them dynamically for Autocomplete. It works up unto the point where ngTagsInput receives an answer from elasticsearch, where I receive the following error in the browser console:

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use
'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in 
suggestionList.items track by track(item), Duplicate key: undefined, 
Duplicate value:{"_index":"data","_type":"tags","_id":"4","_score":1,"_source":{"id":4,"text":"Testinchen"}}
```

The problem here is that the promise I receive contains an array with 4 elements(if I had more reputation I would post a picture here, but no, stack-overflow won't let me :x)

I have tried all night to get ngTagsInput to accept this promise, and the best I managed to do was to somehow retrieve my object If there is only one hits from elasticsearches and not multiple.

The HTML code looks the following:

```
<div data-ng-controller="TagsController">
    <tags-input ng-model="taglist">
        <auto-complete source="loadTaglist($query)"template="tagTemplate"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tagTemplate">
    <span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span>
    <div ng-repeat="model in data._source">
        @{{model}}
    </div>
</script>
```

The @ in front of the {{ model }} here is because this runs on a laravel backend, so never mind that ^^

And the JS is the following:

```
petopia.controller('TagsController', function($scope, tags, esClient) {

    $scope.taglist = [{
        "id" : "1",
        "text": "Pet"
    }];

    $scope.loadTaglist = function(query) {
        var taglist = esClient.search({
            q: "*"+query+"*"
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.hits.hits;
        }, function (error) {
            console.trace(error.message);
        });

        return tags.load(taglist);
    };
});

petopia.service('tags', function($q) {
    this.load = function(taglist) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(taglist);
        console.log(deferred.promise);
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, since I'm at quite a loss here as someone who is quite new to angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You should track it by index when you have duplicates in your array.

`ng-repeat="model in data._source track by $index"`

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but the problem arises even before the data gets to the template. If only one hit is sent by elasticsearch, it kinda works, except for the model then containing both id and text as strings. But thanks for your quick reply!